# Escaping JavaScript special characters from ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I have following C# code in my ASP.NET application:

```
string script = @"alert('Message head:\n\n" + CompoundErrStr + " message tail.');";
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Test", script, true);
```

CompoundErrStr is an error message generated by SQL Server (exception text bubbled up from the stored procedure). If it contains any table column names they are enclosed in single quotes and JavaScript breaks during execution because single quotes are considered a string terminator.

As a fix for single quotes I changed my code to this:

```
CompoundErrStr = CompoundErrStr.Replace("'", @"\'");
string script = @"alert('Message head:\n\n" + CompoundErrStr + " message tail.');";
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Test", script, true);
```

and it now works fine.

However, are there any other special characters that need to be escaped like this? Is there a .Net function that can be used for this purpose? Something similar to HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode but for JavaScript.

**EDIT** I use .Net 3.5

Comment: You can use the same HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode which is more reliable and can convert any special character to quivalent HTML Code.

Comment: @Sreenath HtmlEncode  does not perform escaping for JavaScript strings...

Comment: "CompoundErrStr" alone should be ENcoded before appended with the javascript.

Comment: Server.HtmlEncode doesn't do anything for single quotes.

Comment: @Joe Schmoe: If you are looking for a JS Function which can do a encoding of special characters. You can give a try with "encodeURIComponent" function in js. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: @Sreenath: as I said in my original post I am looking for .Net function.

Comment: @JoeSchmoe You can try with Encoder.HtmlCode from "Microsoft.Security.Application" We used this for blocking XSS.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Note**: for this task you can't (and you shouldn't) use HTML encoders (like `HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode()`) because rules for HTML and for JavaScript strings are pretty different. One example: string `"Check your Windows folder c:\windows"` will be encoded as `"Check your Windows folder c:&#39;windows"` and it's obviously wrong. Moreover it follows HTML encoding rules then it won't perform any escaping for <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd> and <kbd>'</kbd>. Simply it's for something else.

---

If you're targeting **ASP.NET Core** or **.NET 5** then you should use `System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder` class.

---

If you're targeting **.NET 4.x** you can use [HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784638.aspx) method.

---

If you're targeting **.NET 3.x and 2.x**:

**What do you have to encode**? Some characters must be escaped (<kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd> and <kbd>'</kbd>) because they have *special* meaning for JavaScript parser while others may interfere with HTML parsing so should escaped too (if JS is inside an HTML page). You have two options for escaping: JavaScript escape character </kbd> or `\uxxxx` Unicode code points (note that `\uxxxx` may be used for them all but it won't work for characters that interferes with HTML parser).

You may do it manually (with search and replace) like this:

```
string JavaScriptEscape(string text)
{
    return text
        .Replace("\\", @"\u005c")  // Because it's JS string escape character
        .Replace("\"", @"\u0022")  // Because it may be string delimiter
        .Replace("'", @"\u0027")   // Because it may be string delimiter
        .Replace("&", @"\u0026")   // Because it may interfere with HTML parsing
        .Replace("<", @"\u003c")   // Because it may interfere with HTML parsing
        .Replace(">", @"\u003e");  // Because it may interfere with HTML parsing
}
```

Of course </kbd> should not be escaped if you're using it as escape character! This *blind* replacement is useful for *unknown* text (like input from users or text messages that may be translated). Note that if string is enclosed with double quotes then single quotes don't need to be escaped and *vice-versa*). Be careful to keep verbatim strings on C# code or Unicode replacement will be performed in C# and your client will receive unescaped strings. A note about *interfere with HTML parsing*: nowadays you seldom need to create a `<script>` node and to inject it in DOM but it was a pretty common technique and web is full of code like `+ "</s" + "cript>"` to workaround this.

Note: I said *blind* escaping because if your string contains an escape sequence (like `\uxxxx` or `\t`) then it should not be escaped again. For this you have to do some tricks around this code.

If your text comes from user input and it may be multiline then you should also be ready for that or you'll have broken JavaScript code like this:

```
alert("This is a multiline
comment");
```

Simply add `.Replace("\n", "\\n").Replace("\r", "")` to previous `JavaScriptEscape()` function.

---

For completeness: there is also another method, if you encode your string `Uri.EscapeDataString()` then you can decode it in JavaScript with `decodeURIComponent()` but this is more a dirty trick than a solution.

Comment: Excellent answer! Can you clarify what you mean by "blind replacement"?

Comment: `JavaScriptEscape(@"Column 1\tColumn 2")` will be escaped `"Column 1\\tColumn 2"` and `@"\u0032"` will become `"\\u0032"` probably not what you want. Anyway what I mean is that it escapes everything so when you write an escape sequence (then something need to be literally copied) you'll have to do some trickery around it.

Comment: Uri.EscapeDataString and decodeURIComponent was the only "solution" that worked for me to get a URL into a javascript string

Answer (score 9):

While the original question mentions .NET 3.5, it should be known to users of 4.0+ that you can use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("string")`

A second bool parameter specifies whether to include quotation marks (true) or not (false) in the result.

Answer (score 2):

All too easy:

```
@Html.Raw(myString)
```