# C# Mvc resx escape issue with accented letters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-escape-characters

I use resource files in a web project, and sometimes I have accented letters and aphostrophes, which are html-encoded.

So instead of this

```
Errore: non c'è nessun itemKey definito. L'esecuzione della pagina verrà interrotta..
```

I see this

```
Errore: non c&#39;&#232; nessun itemKey definito. L&#39;esecuzione della pagina verr&#224; interrotta..
```

I know that `Html.Raw()` can do the trick, but I was wondering if there are some options that can be set in web config to skip the default escaping? Otherwise I'll be forced to add `Html.Raw()` everywhere

I add resources this way:

```
@(WmXRexManager.WebResxManager.GetString<SharedVerificationResx>(
    () => SharedVerificationResx.ErrorNoItemKey));
```

The `WebResxManager` and the `GetString<T>()` method are irrelevant because when debugging the resource string is correctly retrieved.

Comment: You need to add some source code

Comment: But you actually need escaping in HTML. It's different if text is for JavaScript, in that case you still need escaping but the one for JavaScript instead of HTML one. See also [Escaping JavaScript special characters from ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27545730/1207195)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It did not state this explicitly, but I wanted to know the context where the string is being escaped.

If you use this expression as regular HTML content, the conversion is correct. (you don't need the closing semi-colon, though)

My guess is (assuming that the error message is output using some JS error handling) that you render the string inside JavaScript, and you need to distinguish between HTML-encoding and JavaScript-encoding, as they differ in some cases.

I use an HtmlHelper extension method

```
    public static IHtmlString JsString<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, string s)
    {
        return html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(s));
    }
```

which allows to simply write `@Html.JSString(stringValue)` and have JavaScript strings escaped (inside JS string quotes, of course).

Comment: I just realized that yes, this occurs in ajax error messages coming from the controller. I'm testing your solution, I'll update the question

Comment: It works! But in this way I have to edit all resources I have into javascript code. Is there no way to kind of default it?

Comment: if `WebResxManager.GetString()` is used only for JS error message, put the encoding there. Or add a GetJSString() method. If the method returns an IHtmlString, MVC will directly pass the result without further encoding.